# Rails 3.2 ActivedRecord::Store undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded my application from Rails 3.1 to 3.2 and I am trying to use the new [ActiveRecord:Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) module with a PostgreSQL database.

I created my table:

```
create_table :cupcakes do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.text :recipe
  t.timestamps
end
```

and my model looks like:

```
class Cupcake < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :recipe
end
```

But when I try to construct a new object:

```
cupcake = Cupcake.new
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `store' for #<Class:...>
```

Comment: can you tell me what for you have placed `store :recipe` in `Cupcake` class?

Comment: This isn't my exact code, I sanitized the name/properties for the purpose of the question.  I am using the new store functionality as a replacement for what I have normally used yaml serialization for.

Comment: Well your code as posted works perfectly fine for me... you should post your actual code, something else is going on.

Comment: actually store is not defined as instance method/variable in class, but when you are trying to create object for Cupcake class. its expecting for a method but `store :recipe` is not.

Comment: I've reduced my code to look exactly as I posted and still have the same issue.

Comment: I solved it, my own dumb mistake.  The branch I was working on didn't have the 3.2 migration merged into it.  Works now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I had not run my migration. However, the migration was only to add the column that I was using for store, rather than the entire table.